# What happens with a comma(,) on a MV command?

Tags: linux, bash

I 'fat-fingered' a comma to the end of a mv command

mv path/file .,

The file seems to have disappeared into an ether somewhere.  'find' found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `.` and `..`, the name `.,`  has no special meaning, so the file is there and is actually named `.,`.

Verify that the file is there:

```
ls -l .,
```

You can move it back by just reversing the arguments to `mv`:

```
mv ., path/file
```

Comment: UNIX is really weird: `ls  .,` shows the file indeed, but `ls | fgrep ".,"` does not, as the filename starts with a dot, which makes it a hidden file.

Comment: @Dominique True. It's not that the file `.,` is special in any way. it's just that the `ls` command won't display files starting with a `.` by default. `ls -a | fgrep '.,'` will display it though.

Comment: Oh, I'm not surprised I need to put `-a` to show it in `ls -a | fgrep ...` but I'm surprised I **don't** need to put `-a` for showing it in `ls .,`: I would expect the result of `ls .,` to be empty :-)

Comment: @Dominique :-) Nope, if you name the file explicitly to `ls` it will not hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Linux `ls` command hide files starting with a dot. If you only type `ls` all the files or directories like `.ssh` or `.bashrc` in your home directory will not be displayed. To get all files, you have to give `ls -a` option ( all ).

What you did by moving with `mv path/file .,` is simply moving your source file to the destination `.,`, means your file has exactly this name. By entering `ls -a` or even `ls -l .,' you see it as all other normal files.

You simply can copy or move it again with `mv ., <destination_path/destination_name>`.

You said: " 'find' found nothing."

That is maybe a wrong observation as `find` will see all files even those which starting with a dot.

`find -maxdepth 1  | grep ','` gives:
`./.,`

Maybe you searches in the wrong place?

Comment: My find was (of course) looking for the original filename.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same and I find the ".," easily:

```
ls -ltra | grep ","
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user1 user1          0 Jan 19 10:09 .,
```

The deal is the usage of the `a` switch in the `ls` command: this also shows file, starting with a dot (which are in fact normally invisible in UNIX/Linux), as you can see from the manpage:

```
DESCRIPTION
   List  information  about the FILEs (the current directory by default).  
Sort entries alphabetically if none of
   -cftuvSUX nor --sort is specified.

   Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

   -a, --all
          do not ignore entries starting with .
```

Oh, you need to look into the parent directory of the `path` directory :-)

Comment: Thanks. Never having managed such a thing before I didn't think of ., as a filename.  File (and faith) restored.

Comment: @Hpoonis: glad to help. In case my answer is useful, please upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: I had already flagged the first response as that was the one I used/saw first. ..and (apparently) I am not good enough to vote things up or down.